# A variable width div to hold paragraph elements?

Tags: html, css

Here is a first attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQaQb/6

```
<div id = 'hold'>
    <p class='item'>men1</p>
    <p class='item'>men2</p>
    <p class='item'>men3</p>
</div>

#hold{
  background: #ff0000;
  width: auto;
}
.item{
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

However the width covers the whole window.

How can I have the width expand and contract, depending upon how many p tags are in the holding div.

I want the div width to vary with the inside content.

Production Code:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
**media control
**
*/


#mi_control{
  position:  absolute;
  top:  660px;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu_bottom{
  font-family:  "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size:  12px;
  color:  #000000;
  margin-left:    20px;
  margin-left:    20px;
  display: inline;
}

.menu_bottom:hover{
    cursor: pointer
}

<!--media_control
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - --->


<div id="mi_control">
  <p id="mi_cover_l" class="menu_bottom">Foo &copy; 2013</p>
  <p id="mi_about_l" class="menu_bottom">How</p>
  <p id="mi_privacy_l" class="menu_bottom">Privacy</p>
  <p id="mi_team_l" class="menu_bottom">Team</p>
  <p id="mi_arc_l" class="menu_bottom">Source</p>
</div>
```

Comment: something is causing the div to collapse to 0 width. I can't reproduce in the fiddle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after can be accomplished by adding the following to the css for your div.

```
display: inline-block;
```

so you end up with

```
#hold{
  background: #ff0000;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @pure_code.com It appears to be related to the position: absolute rule on #p_sp.  I disabled that rule in Firebug and the p tags moved to be next to each other instead of stacked.

Comment: any reason the parent div would effect the display of its child like that?

Comment: @pure_code.com CSS styles are generally inherited by children from their parent elements.  You always need to be careful when you use the position style rule.

Answer (score 2):

You need not specify `width:auto` since it is the default. Instead set the container to `display:inline-block`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/nQaQb/2/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, one is to change the display of `#hold` to inline-block. The problem is that block-level elements will span the width of their [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block) by default, which in your case happens to be the *initial* containing block.

http://jsfiddle.net/nQaQb/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
   display:inline; /* or display:inline-block; */
```

to your `#hold` css:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQaQb/3/

Comment: If going for inline you should definitely use `inline-block` instead. `inline` could introduce some unwanted side effects.

Answer (score -1):

Hello you should use an un-ordered list

```
<ul>
<li class='item'>men1</li>
<li class='item'>men2</li>
<li class='item'>men3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While a valid comment, this does not answer the question, and as such should be added as a comment to the original question.